# Passing multiple flags to function in c?

Tags: c, linux

Just as in open() system call user can pass multiple flags separated by pipe ("|", like O_CREAT|O_WRONLY ) but if we look at man page of open system call it will show below given code

```
int open(const char *pathname, int flags);
```

So my question is that since this function contains one argument for flags but user can still pass multiple flags like above example. So can anyone tell me how it is working and if we want to implement similar function how to achieve this?

Comment: Do you know what pipe does?  Do you know what the values of these flags are?

Comment: The "pipe" is actually the [bitwise inclusive OR operator (C11 6.5.12)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.12) ... function receives something like `0b000010000100` and can easily extract the bits that are set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick here is to "one-hot" encode flags as `1 << n` where `0 <= n < sizeof(int) * 8`. So for example, we could have:

```
int FLAG1 = 0x1;
int FLAG2 = 0x2;
int FLAG3 = 0x4;
/* ... */
```

And then write:

```
void func(int flags) {
  if (flags & FLAG1)
    /* FLAG1 is set ... */

  if (flags & FLAG2)
    /* FLAG2 ist set ... */

  /* ... */
}
```

Comment: rather  `void foo(unsigned flags)`

Comment: @P__J__: why would that matter?

Comment: signed numbers are not very good for bitwise operations.

Comment: @P__J__ Guess POSIX, Unix, Linux got it wrong then.  Example -  prototype for open(2), i.e. int open(const char *pathname, int flags);

Comment: It's because nobody in their right mind would ever perform arithmetic operations on flag bits so it doesn't matter at all.